# Get minimum value after HLOOKUP

Tags: excel, lookup, min

I have a lookup table like so:

```
a  b  c  d
1  2  3  4
```

and a row filled with values `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`, for example:

```
d  b  b  d  c
```

I would like to get the minimum value after doing the lookup with the table in a single formula. Something like `MIN(HLOOKUP(...))`. In the example above, the result would be 2.

I know that I could create a new row with the HLOOKUP and later do a MIN on this row. But in my real case, I have several rows and several lookup tables and I would like to avoid having many intermediate rows.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try `HLOOKUP(MIN(), ...))`.

Comment: I can't crack this nut.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108594/does-excel-have-any-map-or-select-functions/5109651#5109651 for some discouraging advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your lookup array is named `LetterValues` and your data is in A1:E1 please try:

```
=HLOOKUP(CHAR(MIN(CODE(A1:E1))),LetterValues,2,0)
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: unfortunately, I put letters in my example to keep it simple but in my real case, they are unordered strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're data starts in cell A1, you can use the following array formula.

```
=MIN(IF(A1:E1="b",A2:E2,""))
```

It basically looks at the range A1:E1 and checks if it equals b. If it does, the formula stores the value from the row below, if not, it stores nothing.

Now that you have an array of all of the numbers associated with b, the MIN functions returns the smallest.

After typing in the formula, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter and curly brackets will appear around the formula.

Comment: In my real case, the lookup table is more complex and I would like avoiding putting one IF statement for each entry in this table.

Comment: Do you have multiple lookup tables? What makes your lookup table so complex that the if within an array wouldn't work? Just to clarify, it's one if function that would give you the final result, not an if per line in the lookup table.

Comment: I have 4 different lookup tables with 16 entries each. I don't want to search for one specific value ("b" in the example) but replace all string by their corresponding value according to one lookup table and then, find the minimum value. With the loohup table in hte example, he table `c a d d` should return 1, and the table `c d d c`should retun 3.